# Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: meteor, mongodb-query, meteor-methods

I cant figure out why my insert query code located in **server/main.js**  is causing this:  `TypeError: callback is not a function` error message.

The following code is located at: **server/main.js**

```
var businessCard = [{PostedDate: moment().add(0, "days").format('MM/DD/YYYY'), sentBy: currentUserId, recipientName: recipientName }];
```

Next line is the insert query:

```
Messages.insert({businessCard: businessCard}, {multi:true});
```

When I run the code, no inserts into the **Messages collection** are carried out, neither do I get any error messages in the browser console, 
however when I check the terminal I see the following error message:

[image: This is the error message I get in the terminal]

When I comment out the insert query, the error message disappears, leading me to think there is something wrong in how I have written this insert code.

Kindly help me figure out what am doing wrong here.

Looking forward to your help

Comment: where is Messages defined? is it known to your server code?

Answer (score 6):

The error is because you use `multi: true` option, `insert` method does not have this option.